# Have I connected the JLI2555 microphone capsule correctly in my circuit?

Tags: amplifier, microphone, jfet

I am working on a DIY Project from [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/LoQu3XXIayc). I have bought the [JLI2555](https://www.jlielectronics.com/content/JLI-2555BXZ3-GP.pdf) microphone capsule but I haven't managed to get it to work.

I connected a JFET with the gate of the capsule and source of the JFET to ground. I also put a resistor at the gate of the JFET and a negative DC voltage to bias it (circuit is below).

[image]

I would expect that when I measure the output with a voltmeter there would be some mV fluctuations as I yell into the microphone, but nothing seems to happen.

My questions are as follows:
Am I doing something wrong? Does the capsule really require a JFET or is it already built in? Does the capsule require external power? In the datasheet it says it works with an operating voltage of 1 V, but the YouTube guy says it doesn't require any voltage to operate.

Answer (score 0):

According to data sheet, at least a JLI-2555BXZ3-GP has no FET built-in and it connects the FET differently. So based on that you did not connect it according to examples.

Also youtube guys may not have a clue what they are doing, so you can never be sure blindly believing what the videos say, you always need to confirm if something is correct or not.

So since the circuit has a FET it obviously needs power from somewhere to work, so your video is wrong. It needs power.

However, depending on where you connect it (e.g. mic input of mobile phone or PC) it may already provide power to the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still not sure how would one go about and connect the capsel to be able to at least see it working? If I connect the jfet to the capsulenand provide a battery as a voltage source should I be able to see voltage fluctuations with a voltmwter if I talk into the mic?

Comment: The fluctuations will be very small. It might be best to just attach the FET and plug it into phone/PC mic input. Mic inputs already support FET-amplified electret capsules, i.e. provide resistors and supplies and DC blocking audio input.

Comment: I was planning on making an amplifier ciruit after the FET and then connect it to a mic input. I am just interested if I set the circuit up in a correct manner? So you connect the gate to te mic and the supply the JFET with 9 volts and a DC Bias and then it should work? Or is this not correct? Should I just follow this datasheet circuit on the internet? 1.5 Volts seems to small for JFET Vds voltage for example as stated in the datasheet?

Comment: You don't need an amplifier because mic inputs are made for mic level signals. You need the capsule and FET buffer, zero other components, just wire it up to mic input

Comment: Ok I will try this. Though I am unsure how I would connect it to the audio cable?Where would the output here be? Below the FET resistor or above it(as in datasheet)? And what audio cable do you use? The headphones one? The mic and headphone cable are integrated in one

Comment: If you intend to connect with 2 wires to standard mic input, FET source is ground and drain is signal/power wire. Use any cable you can find for testing.

Comment: Your 100 ohms resistor should be 2.2k to 10k depending on the specs of your Jfet. The measured drain DC voltage should be half of your 9V supply voltage. Then the output level will be about 0.01VAC when you talk near the mic.

Comment: use the AC volts range on your multimeter,

Comment: I tried changing the resistor and the voltage drop across the FET is very samll 0.3 volts. I tried building the schematic as in the datasheet the voltage drop over the fet is still very small and there are no voltage fluctuations. I also tried connecting it to a mic input and there is nothing to be heard. Nothing seems to work this is quite frustrating

Comment: I don't understand why you must add a resistor. You have not drawn any circuit or FET type or photo of your connections. The datasheet circuit actually you can't use with a PC mic input because that is a two wire connection with bias supply from PC. The datasheet circuit needs external supply and has separate audio wire. If you are trying to measure mic voltage fluctuations with a multimeter, at least set it to AC, and millivolts.

Comment: What resistor are you reffering to? And the abovr circuit ia the one I use but when I connected to the mic inpit I Removed the resistor and connected only the source and drain to the input as you said

Comment: What I find weird is that the voltage drop across the fet is so small with the mic attached but when I short the gate with the source the voltage drop across the JFet goes from 0.3 to like 3 volts approximately(to the voltage one would expect)